# Conditional TLS cert management in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, terraform

I'm trying to create a solution in Terraform whereby I can create TLS certs using lets encrypt or provide my own in an S3 bucket. The problem I'm facing is I can't seem to conditionally run the Let's Encrypt cert generation and upload steps.

How do I make the last two steps conditional? I was thinking about wrapping them in a null_resource, how how do I make a trigger based on external data?

Any tips greatly appreciated! Thanks guys.

N

```
resource "null_resource" "sync_certs" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "mkdir -p ./tmp/certs"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  "aws s3 sync s3://xxxxxx/${var.root_domain_name}/${var.env_name} ./tmp/certs/ && ls -l ./tmp/certs/"
  }
}

resource "tls_private_key" "cert_private_key" {
  count     = "${var.bank_count}"
  algorithm = "RSA"
}

resource "acme_registration" "reg" {
  server_url = "${var.acme_url}"

  account_key_pem = "${tls_private_key.generated_key.private_key_pem}"

  email_address = "xxxxx"
}

resource "acme_certificate" "certificate" {
  count           = "${var.bank_count}"
  server_url      = "${var.acme_url}"
  account_key_pem = "${tls_private_key.generated_key.private_key_pem}"
  common_name     = "${var.bank_names[count.index]}.${var.env_name}.${var.root_domain_name}"

  dns_challenge {
    provider = "route53"
  }

  registration_url = "${acme_registration.reg.id}"
}

resource "local_file" "privkey" {
  count       = "${var.bank_count}"
  content     = "${tls_private_key.generated_key.private_key_pem}"
  filename = "./tmp/certs/${var.bank_names[count.index]}.privkey.pem"
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "tls_private_key_file" {
  count       = "${var.bank_count}"
  bucket      = "xxxx"
  key         = "${var.root_domain_name}/${var.env_name}/${var.bank_names[count.index]}.privkey.pem"
  source      = "./tmp/certs/${var.bank_names[count.index]}.privkey.pem"
  content_type = "text/plain"
  depends_on  = ["local_file.privkey"]
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my understanding is right, are you looking for something like this?

Define a switch on/off variable first `enable=true|false`.

Put the count code in any resource which you want to control.

```
count = "${var.enable ? var.bank_count : 0}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by wrapping the terraform in a script. Here, I can check whether or not I want to use certs in s3, and move in the appropriate files for the terraform out of an override directory. Not pretty but it works!